# jQuery: How to get the second input in a table each column?

Tags: jquery, dom, input

how do I easily get all the first or the last input values in any columns in a table using jQuery? Without the header.

```
<table id="table1">
<tr class="thead">
    <th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th>
</tr>
<tr class="tbody">
    <td>Input1</td><td><input type"text" class="in1"/></td><td><input type"text" readonly class="in2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tbody">
     <td>Input2</td><td><input type"text" class="in1"/></td><td><input type"text" readonly class="in2"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tbody">
     <td>Input3</td><td><input type"text" class="in1"/></td><td><input type"text" readonly class="in2"/></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Here my suggestion:

```
var arr[];
$("#table1 tr").each(function()
{
arr.push($(this).find("input:first").val());
});
```

I would love just doing sth like:

```
$("#table1 input input").each(function()
{...
```

Comment: Your first column appears to be row headers. So you should change them to `<th scope="row">`. This might also simplify selecting the actual first `td` of each row, as would using `thead` and `tbody` to separate your column headers from your data rows. http://jsfiddle.net/tyrqr3w5/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you could use

```
$('#table1 td:nth-child(2) input')
```

and

```
$('#table1 td:last-child input')
```

But you usually give classes to your elements to make everything simpler (as your inputs have roles, you'll also probably want to act on changes, get the values, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. Assumed I gave those elments a class, what would the solution be? i updated the question.